# Mapping RDF/XML data to java objects

Tags: java, jena

i have set up a web crawler that collects data and stores it in rdf/xml file,now i want to map that data to my java objects...how can i do that?

i have found this piece of code that might be usefull for me,but i cant seem to use it properly...it collects subjects,predicates and objects from my rdf/xml file but i can represent this data with my java specified objects,i dont know how...i googled a lot but there arent much usefull things about this so help guys!:D

```
StmtIterator iter = rdfGraph.listStatements();
     while (iter.hasNext()) {

            Statement stmt      = iter.nextStatement();  // get next statement
            Resource  subject   = stmt.getSubject();
            //System.out.print(subject.getNameSpace(  ) + subject.getLocalName(  ));// get the subject
            Property  predicate = stmt.getPredicate(); 
            //System.out.print(" " + predicate.getNameSpace(  ) + predicate.getLocalName(  ));// get the predicate
            RDFNode   object    = stmt.getObject();      // get the object
            //System.out.println(" " + object.toString(  ) + "\n");
            System.out.println(subject + " | "+predicate + " | " + object);

         }
```

this is a part of my rdf file...

```
<rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A12">
<schema:reviewRating rdf:nodeID="A13"/>
<schema:description>descriptiooooon</schema:description>
<schema:datePublished>2012-02-22</schema:datePublished>
<schema:author>Nick M.</schema:author>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://schema.org/Review"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

and i want to represent it with this java object..here is my class...

```
@Namespace(Constants.SCHEMA)
@RdfType("Review")
public class Review extends Thing{

@RdfProperty(Constants.SCHEMA + "author")
private String author;

@RdfProperty(Constants.SCHEMA + "reviewRating")
private Rating reviewRating;

@RdfProperty(Constants.SCHEMA + "datePublished")
private Date datePublished;

@RdfProperty(Constants.SCHEMA + "description")
private String description;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this api could be useful for you:
[XMappr API](https://code.google.com/p/xmappr/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't told us what

> i can represent this data with my java specified objects,

actually means, since you haven't described your Java objects.

Taking a guess, the problem, I think, is that you are accessing the contents of the RDF model one triple (`Statement`) at a time. This is rather a low-level access pattern.  The first thing you need to recognize is that groups of triples with the same subject URI denote information about the same RDF resource. So, one thing you could do is iterate over the subjects of the model, and then list their properties:

```
ResourceIterator i = rdfGraph.listSubjects();
while (i.hasNext()) {
  Resource s = i.next();
  System.out.println( "Graph contains subject " + s );
  for (StmtIterator j = s.listProperties(); j.hasNext(); ) {
    Statement t = j.next();
    System.out.println( "   with property " + t.getPredicate() + 
                        " ---> " + t.getObject() );
  }
}
```

That will give you a sense of the basic level of grouping of statements in your graph. You probably, in fact, only want to start with resources of a certain `rdf:type` which is easy enough to do.

This would be a more common basic pattern for working with RDF data. If you really, really do need a mapping of resources in the graph to Java objects, have a look at projects like [JenaBean](http://code.google.com/p/jenabean/). Be aware though, that that code is quite old, and may need to be adapted to work with current versions of Jena.

Comment: ian can you help me more with this?i added a piece of my rdf/xml and java class...

Comment: Hi Andrej, sorry not to respond sooner, I've been busy. It looks like the code you've shared is some JenaBean code - I put the link in my original answer. As I said then, JenaBean is not an actively maintained project, so it may not work with current versions of Jena. My advice would be to forget about making your resources into Java beans, and just work with the RDF model API using the code sample I suggested. If you're not sure how to do that, I'd advise sending a more complete code sample to the Jena users list. See http://jena.apache.org/help_and_support/index.html for how to do that.